# Android Media player run in background

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I have created android app to stream online radio station and I want to run it in background using service.How to create service to run media player in background?

Here is source code of the application:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private ImageButton buttonPlay,buttonStop,buttonPause;
    private String STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.86.162:8000/";
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    Intent playbackServiceIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
        buttonPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonPause);

        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    mPlayer.reset();
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
                    mPlayer.prepareAsync();

                    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                        {
                            mPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                startService();
            }
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mPlayer.stop();

                stopService();
            }
        });

        buttonPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mPlayer.pause();

                stopService();
            }
        });

        playbackServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
    }

    private void startService()
    {
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackgroundService.class));
    }
    private void stopService()
    {
        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackgroundService.class));
    }
}

    public class BackgroundService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener
{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private String STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.86.162:8000/";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try
        {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try
            {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                    {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please research before asking, this is so basic that you can find out a lot of answers on the Internet. Here an example [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm)

Comment: I don't know what to put instead of R.raw.s: mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s);// raw/s.mp3

Comment: I am not using mp3 file,I am using this: "http://178.149.86.162:8000/"

Comment: dont use `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s)`, use the way you did `mPlayer = new MediaPlayer()` and then `mPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);`

Comment: You have not initialized `mediaPlayer` in `BackgroundService`.Do it in `onCreate` method. Secondly, in `onStartCommand`, you should do the same thing as you do in `onClickListener` of `buttonPlay`. Then, call this service in that `onClickListener`

Comment: According to your code now, the radio will be played in both `MainActivity` and `BackgroundService`. Remove the code in `onClickListener` of `buttonPlay` and just leave the `startService`. The `intent` in `startService(intent)` and `stopService(intent)` must be the same so that `service` can be stopped. You should better research more about the `Service`  before trying this example

Comment: Please add a language tag. Is this Java?

Comment: yes it is java.